# Cypress UI sees my spec files but not working

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I have just created a spec file under that path is integration>mweb>account>address-mweb.spec.ts. Cypress UI sees my all spec files but while running it cannot establish a connection with tests.

How can I fix this, any idea?

p.s there is no network issue.

[Waiting to connect on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJXwv.png)

[Cypress UI appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KI1u.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it the same with `Electron`, seems the issue with the chrome browser. Before checking others, please try with Electron

Comment: You are totally right. It seems only with the chrome browser. But a couple of days ago, I could run tests with chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Update the cypress version to the latest. It might help you to fix the issue.

Comment: I upgraded to 9.5.0 but still continue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe check your hosts file, see whether

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

is in there

Comment: Yes, localhost like that.